# How to configure Windows 2008 R2 server for LAN and wireless internet connections

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking

For special testing purposes, we need a Windows server to allow the following:

1. A team member can log in remotely to the server.
2. When remotely logged in, they can disconnect the wireless connection, perform a few tests, and then reconnect the wireless connection.
3. In general, the LAN connection would just be used for the remote login, the wireless connection would be used for performing tests including using a web browser to test certain web sites, etc.

How can we successfully configure the server to support 2 network connections like this?  (A regular LAN connection + a wireless connection).  And also make sure that the tests we perform using the browser utilize the wireless connection for the outgoing internet activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward.

1.) Connect your Server to the network via Ethernet Cable & Wifi
2.) Enable Remote Desktop or LogMeIn or any remote access software.
3.) Change the "Provider Order" by going into your Network Connections then Advanced Settings

This link gives more information : https://superuser.com/questions/436256/can-i-choose-wifi-over-ethernet-lan